# bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am having some problems when deploying [nginx](https://blog.vu-review.com/nginx-la-gi.html). I have another service running in port 80, now I wan to install nginx and use server block with unique hostname port 80. But when I start nginx service, I get this error.

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not enough to specify a unique hostname. The hostname can only be determined *after the connection has been accepted*, so it is not something that Nginx can use while binding the main sockets.

If you have multiple IP addresses, you can configure both programs to listen on different addresses. If you don't, then you will need to use a reverse proxy, where one program receives all port-80 connections, keeps some requests, and forwards other requests to the other program. (Nginx itself can be a reverse proxy, using proxy_pass.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I think my problem is reverse proxy.